# Asp control ListBox selected item is coming null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Asp listbox control with id skill,when i bind the options through jquery and select it on onsubmit in c# listbox is coming empty.but it works if i put the same option in html

```
var selected = skill.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

The items added to the `ListBox` control through javascript will never reach the server.The items are created **on the server** and are added to ViewState when the page is constructed and sent to the browser.

You cannot modify `ListBox` items in javascript and then post them back to the server as this is a security threat.Imagine a hacker could modify your list through javascript and post the changes to the server.

As a work around there are three options I can think of:

1. Populate the `ListBox` from code behind.
2. Populate the `ListBox` from .ASPX.
3. Populate the list box through javascript,like you're doing now,but when an item is selected instead of calling the server side `SelectedIndexChange` call a javascript function and post back to the server using `$.ajax` and `[WebMethod]`